# Error trying to run bare React Native app with gesture handler

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

**Background**

Hey everyone, I'm building my first React Native app without Expo. I'm trying to use `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`, I've followed the instructions provided in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project) every step of the way. I'm then trying to add `react-native-appearance` to handle dark mode preference from device. However, from here on out things get tricky when I try to run the app using an Android emulator.

**Problem**

> ERROR  react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure
> you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked
> properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..).

And that is followed by a number of variations of this error message:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[8],
> "./NativeAppearance").NativeAppearance.initialPreferences')

**What I've tried**

As I've mentioned earlier, I've referred to the Navigation docs, but also to all the following:

- [Gesture handler docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation) I've exhausted all options here, from the basic stuff to manual linking.
- [Gestutre handler github issue 671](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/671)
- [All options from Appearance docs](https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance#linking)

**How you can help me**

I would really appreaciate if someone could let me know how to solve this issue, I imagine it has to do with compatibility with Appearance, so I'll be checking that out while I wait for an answer.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution for this?